# Can someone explain behind the scenes why this Jquery Hover image command doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Can someone explain behind the scenes why this Jquery Hover image command doesn't work?

I have seen working examples but I want to know WHY this doesn't work. (improper syntax is not the answer I am looking for)

```
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#banner").fadeIn(1500,function(){
                $("#contactBt").fadeIn('slow');
            });
        $("#contactBt").hover(function(){
            $("#contactBt").css("src","images/contactBtHover.png");
        },function(){
            $("#contactBt").css("src","images/contactBtNoHover.png");
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body bgcolor=212121>

    <div style="margin-top:15%; margin-left:10%" >
        <img id="banner" style="display:none;" src="images/banner.png" width=1000 height=275/>
    </div>

    <img id="contactBt" style="display:none; margin-top:0%; margin-left:10%" src="images/contactBtNoHover.png" width=250/>
</body>
```

Basically I just want it to say when the mouse is hovering over the image change its image source to a different image. Vice Verse on the way back

Comment: Because `.css()` is not the correct jQuery method for setting an image's `src`.

Comment: Also not that `hover` has been removed in the latest jQuery version,

Comment: @elclanrs - It has! Do you have proof ???

Comment: Right I thought it was `hover` but it's `on('hover')` that [was removed](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event), my bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be:

```
$("#contactBt").attr("src","images/contactBtHover.png");
```

as `src` is an attribute, not a style.

Comment: I would love to accept your answer in a few moments when I am able to. However, if people continue to downvote this then I will just  delete it. Sorry!

Comment: @user1167442 - Depends I guess. `.hover()` [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/aJLz5/2/) in all versions of jQuery, and I'm not sure if it was deprecated or not? The hover event, as in `.on('hover')` was surely removed not long ago, but that's something completely different. The proper events to replace `.hover()` would be mouseenter/mouseleave, and you can pass objects to `on()` which makes it look a lot neater.

Comment: Wait a minute.  I got confused.  hover() was not deprecated.  I guess my answer wasn't better.  Also I learned the difference between mouseover and mouseenter.  Thanks